# OpenCV keypoint copy does not work properly

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to copy keypoints from one vector to another keypoint vector. I want to do this so that I can split the keypoints to thread them. The below is done by using all the keypoints found. (Copying is the problem, not the splitting, and these are done in the main thread, no threading here)

The values of **keypoint1** and **keypoint2** after copying are the same, but when I put them through the extracting descriptor and matching algorithm, keypoint1 and keypoint2 produces different results.

**keypoint1** produces accurate results, whereas **keypoint2** produces a lot of wrong results. I am using `ORB algorithm` for detecting keypoints and descriptor extraction, and `FlannBasedMatcher` for matching. I have tried a few methods to copy the keypoints, I tried `push_back()` too, but its the same.

Method 1:

```
keypoint2.clear();
keypoint2.insert(keypoint2.begin(), keypoint1.begin(), keypoint1.end());
```

Method 2:

```
keypoint2.clear();
keypoint2.resize(keypoint1.size());
for (int i = 0; i < keypoint1.size(); ++i) {
    keypoint2[i].pt.x = keypoint1[i].pt.x;
    keypoint2[i].pt.y = keypoint1[i].pt.y;
    keypoint2[i].size = keypoint1[i].size;
    keypoint2[i].angle = keypoint1[i].angle;
    keypoint2[i].response = keypoint1[i].response;
    keypoint2[i].octave = keypoint1[i].octave;
    keypoint2[i].class_id = keypoint1[i].class_id;
}
```

After copying the keypoints

```
extractor->compute(GrayImage2, keypoint2, descriptor_img2);
matcher.match(descriptor_img1, descriptor_img2, matches);
```

I can tell that its wrong because after this step, they go through the same filtering step to get better results. The difference in amount of correct data from using keypoint1 and keypoint2 are very large.

I tried using pointers to split the keypoint too, but I couldn't get the pointer to point at part of the keypoint vector.

**Update:**

The original plan was to split up the image into sections using roi, and use detect() with std::thread, then recombine the keypoints found and split them equally and thread again for compute(). I thought that there was an increase in fps...after checking again, the speed is the same. After more searching on the internet, I think I can't parallelize detect() and compute() this way. If someone knows why, I hope you can tell me. I'm going to try TBB.

I probably won't have a need to copy the keypoints like in the above, but if you know why, I would still like to know, and maybe for anyone who needs to do this in the future. Just a few more information from my debug, even if I initialize another extractor, i.e.`Ptr<ORB> extractor2 = ORB::create(...)` or use back the same one, and extract descriptors from both the copied keypoint, and the original one, and place the descriptors into different descriptor containers, and I match twice, using the two descriptors, to the one in the previous image. Both the matches would be correct.